# HTML/CSS - Styling going to both <li> sections on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I've got some a small problem with a html page at the moment.

The page is setup with 2 blog posts. They are both in there own bordered sections using `<li>`.

I also use `<li>` for my navigation and for the blog posts but the styling is going around both.

I know it must be to do with creating a class or ID or something but I just can't get it to work. Thanks in advance!!

Any pointers would be great thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="coursework1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Hobbies</title>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modernizr-custom.73764.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/webshim/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    $.webshims.polyfill('mediaelement');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hobbies </h1>
<nav class="nav">
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="/clients/">Newsletter</a></li>
</nav>
<p>  
       <ul> 
    <li> 
        <p>  <h2> Pompey Win! - March 14, 2012 </h2> </p> 
        <img class="focus pic" src="pompeygoal.jpg"
   style="float:left; width:400px; height:300px; border:none;"
    />
       <img class="focus pic" src="pompeychallenge.jpg"
   style="margin-left: 50px; width:400px; height:300px; border:none;"
    />
     <img class="focus pic" src="andyawford.jpg"
   style="float:right; width:400px; height:300px; border:none;"
    />  
        <p> On tuesday evening of this week, I went to Portsmouth. Unfortunately, I do support them... But being the good fan I am , I still made the trip down to the south coast to show my support. It turned out to be a really good evening though as we ended up winning 3-2!</p> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
        <p> <h2>Notting Hill Carnvial - March 13, 2012 </h2> </p> 
        <video width="480" height="360" controls id="nhVid">
    <source src="NottingHillVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="NottinHillVid.webm" type="video/webm"> </video>   
     <p> Every summer, I always look forward to Notting Hill Carnival. This year was my third year, and I had a great time. It was extremely wet, however this did not dampen spirits and everyone still had a smile on their face. I saw loads of music and also had some really great jerk chicken. <p>  
    </li> 
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
  background-color:#808080; 
  font-family:symbol, 'Standard Symbols L';
  margin: 0 0 100px;
}

h1 { 
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size:350%;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
}

#tableAbout { 
  width:100%; cellpadding:10; cellspacing:5;
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white; table align:center;
}

.nav{  
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(grey, black);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(grey, black);
  background: linear-gradient(grey, black);
}

.nav li{
    display:inline;
}

.nav a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    color: white;
    font-size:25px; 
}

.nav a:hover{
  -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
  -webkit-stroke-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px white;
}

td[target] {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#newsletterForm {
    color: white;
}

footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px; 
  clear:both;
  left: 0;
  font-color:black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.focus {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.focus:hover {
  border: 70px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


li { 
  background-color: rgba(194, 181, 158, .5); 
  border: 1px solid rgb(194, 181, 158); 
  border-radius: 10px; 
  margin: 10px 0; 
  padding:10px;
}

li:nth-child(even){ 
  background-color: rgba(242, 224, 131, .5);  
  border: 1px solid rgb(242, 224, 131); 
}

ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a class on each li. PS posting code is better than providing a link to download a zip

Comment: could you please please please post the working code? I've tried loads of stuff with classes and I still can't get it working

Comment: You are opening an ul tag and closing it with ol tag.

Answer (score 2):

I won't download the zip but as you mentioned that both blog posts are in their own section using `<li>`, it could just work like this (example class names and CSS):

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="blogOne">
    content
  </li>
  <li class="blogTwo">
  content
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.blogOne
{
   color:red;
}
.blogTwo
{
   color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're simply targeting the **li** selector in your CSS. This is going to find any and all **li** elements on the page and apply the styling to them.

If you want to only target the **li** elements that are supposed to be your blog posts, you can place them in their own div, and then target only the **li** elements inside the div - something like this:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="blogs">
    <li> Whatever </li>
    <li> Something else </li>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.blogs li {
    css-attribute: whatever;
}
```

.

---

### NOTE:

I would highly recommend not using a separate class for each blog post. That method is not extensible - i.e. it seems reasonable for 2 blog posts, but what happens when you have 1,000?

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML as well. You need to have li inside either a ul or ol.

This:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="/clients/">Newsletter</a></li>
</nav>
```

Needs to be this:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/work/">Hobbies</a></li>
      <li><a href="/clients/">Newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You are also opening a ul on your second list but closing it with a ol.

Now to get different styles you just need to put another class on the second ul to target that one specifically.

For example:

```
<ul class="blog-list">
```

Now you can write a class like this:

```
.blog-list {
    list-style:none;
    padding: none;
}

.blog-list li {
    //Styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you open an `ul` list, you should close it with an `/ul`not an `ol`.
2. In the `nav` element, remove `li` items and keep the anchors inside nav, or wrap them in a list.
3. You can use either an `ol` for nav, and `ul` for content, or use same list type and style them regarding the list's parent(as in declaring a general styling for ul elements and overwrite some styles with `nav ul` for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's beter to give each "ul" a different class like:

```
ul.nav {/*css styles*/}
  ul.nav > li {}
  ul.nav > li:nth-child(X) {}


ul.second {/*css styles*/}
  ul.second > li {}
  ul.second > li:nth-child(X) {}
```

In this manner you can be sure that you're targeting the right li or ul

Note: I saw some `<p>` tags that where not closed at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You should assign a class name to your nav list items and another class name to your blog list items.